# Performing geospatial analysis in R?

Tags: r

I obtained a rectangular sort of image when I subset shapefile on the raster image. I want to get exact irregular shaped image so that I can proceed my classification to that particular area (B is my raster image):

```
boundryfile<-readOGR(dsn="E:\\FYP guide\\SUPARCO 2013\\Jamal Garhi",layer="Jamal Garhi")
B_crop<-crop(x=B,y=boundryfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

R and raster crops to a bounding box so you will need to also mask to only retain the area of interest. Mask works by setting values inside or outside of a shape to a value usually NA in this context.
See raster::mask command